# Silverlight application crashes browser refresh

Tags: silverlight, crash

I just upgraded application to VS2012. Same SL5, just upgraded to async/await.

Everything seem to be working, but I can't restart application by refreshing browser. It goes white screen which I assume indication that it crashes. But how do I figure out why it is doing it?

EDIT: Very very stange. I just noticed if I click on address line in IE10 and hit enter - it refreshes just fine. If I hit refresh button (round arrow) - it goes blank.

I assume this is different "refresh types" in IE?!

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser and check if any exception are written to console. Is async/await available for silverlight?

Comment: async/await available via AsyncTargetingPack

Comment: Nope. No exception written. While dev tools were open I hit refresh couple of times and sometimes app would load and sometimes it wouldn't. Most times it didn't load..

Comment: Do you start the silverlight application from Visual Studio with Debugger attached?

Comment: Yes, I do. Just created simple SL5 application to make sure it is not new behavior of VS2012. It works properly. I assume my app crashes somewhere, but I have no idea how to catch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in IE and silverlight plugin
You can refere to this website: (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789004/ie10-shows-blank-page-upon-refreshing-silverlight-app)

Cheers